# Read multiple files with the same number of lines in the same loop in C

Tags: c, file, stream, scanf

I have two files, both with 47k lines. I'm trying to read each file's line at the same time. The problem is that only the first line of each file is read. That's the code i wrote:

```
id_region = fopen(argv[3], "r");
prediction=fopen(argv[4], "r");

int prediction_class, class, region;

while ((fscanf(id_region,"%d  1:%d",&class,&region) == 2) && (fscanf(prediction,"%d",&prediction_class) == 1))
{

     fprintf(stderr,"\nRegião %d",region);
     fprintf(stderr,"\nClasse %d",class);
     fprintf(stderr,"\nPredição %d",prediction);
}
```

what's the problem with my code?

EDIT: I tried this code, but i have a segmentation fault when I run it. What's wrong here?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    FILE* id_region;
    FILE* prediction;   

    id_region = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    prediction=fopen(argv[2], "r");

    char line[50];
    char line2[50];

    int prediction_class,region,temp1,temp2;

    while((fgets (line,10,prediction) != NULL) && (fgets (line2, 10, id_region)!=NULL))
    {
      //formating the input
      temp1=fscanf(line,"%d",&prediction_class);
      temp2=fscanf(line2,"%d",&region);

      fprintf(stderr,"\nRegion: %d",region);
      fprintf(stderr,"\nPrediction: %d",prediction_class);
    }

    fclose(prediction);
    fflush(prediction);
    fclose(id_region);
    fflush(id_region);   

    return(0);


 }
```

**SOLVED BY THIS CODE- THANKS!**

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

  FILE* id_region;
  FILE* prediction; 

  id_region = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  prediction=fopen(argv[2], "r");

  char line[50];
  char line2[50];

  int prediction_class,region,class;
  contador=0;

  while((fgets(line,10,prediction)!= NULL) && (fgets(line2, 20, id_region)!=NULL))
 {


  sscanf (line,"%d", &prediction_class);
  sscanf (line2,"%d  1:%d",&class,&region);
  fprintf(stderr,"\nRegion: %d",region);
  fprintf(stderr,"\nPrediction: %d",prediction_class);



 }


   fclose(prediction);
   fflush(prediction);
   fclose(id_region);
   fflush(id_region);   

    return(0);


}
```

Comment: Don't tag `C++` when you need `C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `fscanf()`, you should use `fgets()` to get each line, and use `sscanf()` to get formatted input from the lines.

---

For the edited question, I spotted at least two problems: you are still using `fscanf()`, while it should be `sscanf()`. And you are using `fflush()` **after** closing the streams with `fclose()`. Actually `fclose()` will cause the streams to flush, you don't need to flush them manually.

Comment: Should I put fscanf in a loop and fgets also in a loop? can you see my edit above?

Comment: Thanks, i breath softly to be calm and tried your solution. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You ve said line. You then must skip the end of line character. Add `\n` in the `fscanf` or use `fseek`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what's that ?

```
int prediction_class, class, region;
```

`class` as `int` ?

`fgets (char *_Buf, int _MaxCount, FILE *_File)` will do the job better.
I'm using it in my current project and it works fine.

Comment: sorry, class is a variable, i just traslated its name from my mother language :-)

Comment: But how to do this in a loop with 2 files at the same time?

Comment: You read the line with `fgets (char *_Buf, int _MaxCount, FILE *_File) ` and format it with  `sscanf(const char *_Src, const char *_Format, ...) ` as Yu Hao already said...

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working. I'm sorry but what's wrong?

while((fgets (line,1,prediction) != NULL) && (fgets (line2, 10, id_region)!=NULL))
{  
   a=fscanf(line,"%d",&prediction);
   b=fscanf(line2,"%d  1:%d",&class,&region);

I want the variables prediction, class and region to be read in each loop iteration but this code freezes

Comment: Please edit your question and update the current code, I don't know which type the new variables (mentioned in your comment above) have. And post the full code please, a & b do not seem to be used by anything.